# At what point is the gradient equal to (0,-1)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I drew a level curve of a given function, how would one "loosely" determine at what point/area on that level curve the gradient vector is $(0,-1)$? What's the general idea here?

The level curve I am currently looking at is shaped like the number 8, but tilted a bit to the right, lying in the 1st and 4th quadrant of the xy-plane: $\textit{8}$. It tells me that the gradient vector is $(0,-1)$ at the top of the 8.... why?

The answer is D in the following::

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture or an expression you can share with us?

Comment: Pic added. The answer is supposedly D.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that the gradient is ortogonal on the level curve?

Comment: Yes, the gradient is orthogonal to the level curve, and the only two marked places where the level cure moves in the right direction for the gradient to be $(0, y)$ for any $y$ are A and D. Why isn't A a correct answer?

Comment: @Arthur: Perhaps A is excluded because the curve self-intersects there, so no simple statement can be made about "the gradient".

Comment: @hardmath There are plenty of surfaces which have a well-defined gradient everywhere and still a self-intersecting level curve like this at some point. Just note that the gradient has to be orthogonal to both of the incoming curves.

Comment: @Arthur: Can we exclude A based on what you just wrote, given that one incoming curve is vertical and one is horizontal?

Comment: @hardmath Yes. It means that if the gradient is well defined at A, then it is zero. You often see level curves behave like that at saddle points.